# Extract Numbered Headings with Docx4j

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I'm trying do extract a text from a docx file using docx4j.
So far I can extract all written text and images, but I'm having problems while extracting numbered headers (as below) and lists.

```
1. Heading 1
       text....
1.1 Heading 2
       text....
       text....
2. Heading 1
       text....
2.1 Heading 2
    ....
    a)
    b)
    c)
```

Opening a docx file, inside documents.xml, I found that all these headers and lists are inside numPr tags.

A "1. Header" is

```
<w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
    <w:numId w:val="2"/>
</w:numPr>
```

"1.1 Header" is

```
<w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
    <w:numId w:val="2"/>
</w:numPr>
```

And an a), b), c) list  is

```
<w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
    <w:numId w:val="22"/>
</w:numPr>
...
<w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
    <w:numId w:val="22"/>
</w:numPr>
...
<w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
    <w:numId w:val="22"/>
</w:numPr>
```

My question is: is there an easy way to get these headers text (1. ; 1.1; a)...)? A simple extraction with P.toString() or using JAXBElement just give me the written text in paragraph and not the list.
Or how can I convert the tags into text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [listnumbering Emulator class](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/listnumbering/Emulator.java) works out what the numbers are.

It is used for (X)HTML and PDF output.

You can use it yourself directly; another approach you could try would be to use FOP's TXT output.  Try Docx4J.toFO with an FOSettings object with setApacheFopMime("text/plain")

If you do experiment with FOP's TXT format, note the advice about recommended settings, linked from http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/About-the-format-TXT-td37351.html

Comment: Thank you! 
I'll try these solutions.